# Microsoft edge v 92.0.902.73 freezes when using datalist with <input type="text" /> workaround

Tags: microsoft-edge

I am developing an internal website that should be accessed by Microsoft edge only. But, in the latest build, we have experienced A LOT of sudden crashes. It's related to `<input type="text">` with `list` property.
It only happens, when you try to hover mouse over the dropdown menu, or press UP key too many times. Then, your browser crashes. I have found, that some developers also experience this issues as seen [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/latest-release-of-edge-crashes/m-p/2592611) and [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/enterprise/microsoft-edge-newest-version-92-issues-with-select-boxes/m-p/2606314). I hope it will get fixed, but for now, I need to deploy emergency fix to production { (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ }, as a lot of our web applications just decide to crash. This can be devastating for the end users, as they need to spend around hour of work redoing the process.

TLDR; Is there any know workaround for this issue?

Reproduceable example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-aIdcmZzJ0 (not mine)

code: ! CAUSES CRASH WHEN YOU RUN IT ON EDGE v 92.0.902.73, EVEN ON STACK OVERFLOW !

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <!-- When you press the down arrow key twice, Edge crashes. -->
      <h1>This html causes crash on Edge 92.0.902.55</h1>
      <label>Options:</label>
      <input type="text" list="options" />
      <datalist id="options">
         <option>Option 1</option>
         <option>Option 2</option>
         <option>Option 3</option>
      </datalist>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ┬─┬ノ(ಠ_ಠノ) please respect the table.

Comment: Ok, ok, @GenerousBadger, sorry... (ヘ･_･)ヘ┳━┳

Comment: I mean depending on how often this feature is used, rolling back that specific version of Edge might be the correct course of action. I guess simply disabling the list everywhere is not an acceptable workaround.

Comment: Yeah, I guess, I have told it to he IT department and they replied that they cannot do that becuase: "Microsoft edge is somewhat 'special' when setting up rules on a local network." They, for some reason, are not able to roll back specific version of edge :/... I mean, I could go around and do it manually, but I would prefer to not do that. Also, this feature is used in almost every app (that's why the importance).

Comment: That sounds weird. According to [Microsoft themselves](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-rollback) there's two ways to do it (starting with Edge 86, it's possible that it was harder/impossible before that). But I'm no admin, so I might be missing stuff. Unfortunately I can't help you otherwise. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, idk, I'm not an admin either, so I'm not going to argue with them :/... I'll try to show them the resource you sent tho :D. Thanks for you help!

Comment: After testing, I found that this issue only occurs when the option is already at the boundary and after `keyup/keydown` event(When the boundary is exceeded). If the value of `<input>` is a fixed `option` value, then you can choose to use `<select>` and it will work correctly. You can also give feedback to the relevant team on this issue, just press `Shift+Alt+I` in Chromium Edge, then edit your question and send it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we had this issue too with fields that had autocomplete on, but seems solved as from edge 94.0.992.58 on extended stable channel (we will switch to extended stable channel to avoid these kind of bugs impacting our business)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. To be honest I forgot about this question and I should probabbly close it :D